# How do you make a 2d animation of a 3d object rotating given a lot of the parameters for it?

Tags: animation

I'm not looking for the exact answer, I'm trying to get that on my own. But given parameters like the number of frames, perspective projection, angle and axis of rotation and frame vertices, I just want a point in the right direction on how to even get started. The 3d object being rotated is also given, being an imported model.

Comment: This is not enough detail to give any specific advice. So here is a potential pointer: use a 3D plot, but set the `ViewPoint` and `ViewAngle` such that you are looking straight on to one "face" of the axis cube, to give the impression of 2D.

Comment: How do I use a 3D plot for an imported 3D object? I do have an 'eye location' point, so that probably determines the face.

Comment: What is the format of the imported 3D object? That's why we need more details.

Comment: Oh, the 3D object is an OBJ file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a 3D object rotating around the z-axis. The point of view is set to give an ortographic projection that "looks like" a 2D representation.

```
lvb = Normal@ ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Beethoven"}, "GraphicsComplex"];

Animate[
  Graphics3D[
    {Rotate[#, angle Degree, {0, 0, 1}] & /@ lvb},
    ViewPoint -> {0, -Infinity, 0},
    Boxed -> False
  ],
  {angle, 0, 360, 10}
]
```

[image: rotating bust of Beethoven]